# Pixelart gets fuzzy using UIImageView

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiimageview, pixel

I have an 16 * 16 pixel art image which i want to use in my  iOS app. 
but when i select the image at my UIImageView the picture gets really blurry.

I think it has something to do with the way the image gets filtered, but i couldn't find any filtering options.
I already tried changing a lot of options, but just can't get it to work

How do i fix this?

( i am using iOS 7, Xcode 5.1.1, OS X 10.9 Mavericks and a iPhone 4S  (i don't think this info is needed, but just in case))

EDIT:

Here's an image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3Yms.png

As you can see, the image on the right in photoshop looks great, but the image on the left in Xcode looks fuzzy

Comment: Can you add some code and a screenshot?

Comment: I added an image (please ignore the console, that's already fixed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that scaling procedure interpolates pixels position and size while scaling it. If you want to use sharp pixelart-images you must prepare all resources and never rely on scaling by setting

```
_imageView.contentMode = UIVIewContentModeCenter;
```

OR
set scaling filters to value `kCAFilterNearest`

```
[_imageView.layer setMagnificationFilter:kCAFilterNearest];
[_imageView.layer setMinificationFilter:kCAFilterNearest];
```

if you like the second way, i'd recommend to set all ImageView frames with EVEN (2,4,6,8 etc) sizes and origins to avoid pixel misalign

Comment: That works, but makes it smaller. I want it bigger but with the same sharp edges and no blur

Comment: If you want bigger pixelated pic - resize (`CMD+OPTION+I`) it to your size (96x96px) in photoshop with option `interpolation` switched off

Comment: sorry, `interpolation` must be switched ON and have value `nearest neighbor`

Comment: This isn't how i want to solve it. I want to use 16*16 images and just scale them up without the fuzziness

Comment: And how would i do that? i want to do it right. ( talking about the core graphics thingy)

Comment: Try this one : `[imageView.layer setMinificationFilter:kCAFilterNearest];`

Comment: And this : `[imageView.layer setMagnificationFilter:kCAFilterNearest];` this should solve all scaling blur

Comment: those two lines are the same, what should the second one be?

Comment: not the same: there are MAGNIFICATION and MINIFICATION filters

Comment: It works! thank you so much!. Sorry about the magnification/magnification thingy, they look similar.

Comment: thank you for not wasting much time to solve your prblem together )